# How do I call CPanel API from separate website

Tags: php, cpanel, cpanel-uapi

After reading as much as I can from the CPanel documentation and forum posts I have come to the conclusion that what I want to do is not possible but I thought I would have one last try just in case.

I have a server that hosts a number of domain accounts that are managed by CPanel, some of the domains have a Wordpress supported website that includes a plugin to provide services to the users.

I don't have root access, that is only available to the service company that host the server.

I would like to provide a webpage (php) that displays the email forwarders to selected users who do not have access to CPanel.

Is this possible?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Are you able to _use_ the API, with whatever level of access to the CPanel you have? If not, then this likely won't be possible - I doubt CPanel stores this info anywhere where you'd have access via PHP from the website context.

Comment: I tried instantiating CPANEL and got an error saying it could not locate the CPanel socket, it sounds like I need root access to do this